# Incompatible pointer type - sending void to parameter type void NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

```
- (void)restorePurchasesButtonTapped {

    [soundManager playTapSound];
    persistor = [RMStore defaultStore].transactionPersistor;

    [[RMStore defaultStore] restoreTransactionsOnSuccess:^{

        if ([persistor isPurchasedProductOfIdentifier:@"RemoveAds"]) {
            [SVProgressHUD showSuccessWithStatus:@"Purchases restored, ads removed!"];
            [FXKeychain defaultKeychain][@"AdsRemoved"] = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
        } else {
            [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:@"Looks like you don't have any previous purchases!"];
        }


    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:@"Problem restoring purchases"];
    }];


}
```

Edit:  Sorry for not being clear with the question.  The error I'm receiving is the following: "Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void'(^)(void) to parameter of type 'void(^)NSArray*__strong)'

I am not returning an Array but NSArray was mentioned in the bug.  If I can give any more information please let me know, kind of new to coding and trying to fix an error from someone else's code project so I don't have a great understanding of the code

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take the time to format proerply your question and have a look to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: And you need to ask a question along with your code... Not just allude to one in your title.

Comment: Where in your code are you trying to return an nsarray?

Comment: edited the question..anything else i can add to be helpful please let me know and sorry didn't provide full details first time

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `restoreTransactionsOnSuccess` is expecting a different block argument.

Try:

```
[[RMStore defaultStore] restoreTransactionsOnSuccess:^(NSArray *transactions){
```

Answer (score 0):

The type `void (^)(void)` is a reference to a block (`(^)`) which takes no arguments (`(void)`) and returns nothing (`void`). The error states this is what you are providing and it is incompatible with the parameter type of `void (^)(NSArray * __strong)` - which is a reference to a block which takes an array and returns nothing. The definition of the method you are calling is:

```
- (void)restoreTransactionsOnSuccess:(void (^)(NSArray *transactions))successBlock
                             failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failureBlock;
```

You need to provide a success block which accepts a single `NSArray *` as argument, e.g.:

```
^ (NSArray *transactions) { ... }
```

HTH